# How does lexicographic comparison work internally in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, lexicographic

I was recently learning about the `sort()` array method in JavaScript. When called without an argument, it sorts the given elements lexicographically.

I know what does lexicographical comparison mean. But I am confused in one thing...

I was wondering how does a JavaScript engine perform lexicographic comparison between two strings internally. Does it actually iterate over each character one-by-one and perform the check, or that there is some other mathematical flavor added to these comparisons internally?

Comment: I believe Javascript uses merge sort for non-numeric arrays.

Comment: No no, I just want to know about the internals of lexicographic comparison of two strings.

Comment: That actually has nothing to do with `sort()` specifically, it's just the same comparison that `strA < strB` (and `<=`, `>=`, `>`) uses

Comment: @Bergi I know about that already :)

Comment: @coderboy You might want to put that in the question so that it doesn't get derailed into discussions about sort comparison :-)